# Syncing contacts through exchange

Tags: exchange

Just a quick question. I know you can sync from exchange to your windows phone. But is it possible to push contacts from your phone to the exchange server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8/239020-save-numbers-exchange-instead-hotmail.html), when you create a new contact, if you have more than one source of contacts, you can specify where it gets saved (eg. outlook.com, gmail, exchange). You simply tap on the place where you want it to be saved.Once you are finished creating a contact it gets saved to the location you previously selected.